# Navigating back to the same Google Chrome page in Windows 8 after accessing another program

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

I started developing **Android** apps using **Eclipse IDE** with **Windows 7**. In the course of developing I would be constantly consulting **SO** via **Google Chrome** and navigating back to **Eclipse IDE** to try out a solution that I found; and then back to **SO** if the solution didn't work.

Recently, I bought a computer with **Windows 8**, and each time I navigate back to **Eclipse** (which is on a **taskbar** on **desktop**) I lose the **SO** page that I was on and can't return to it.When I navigate to **Google Chrome** I just get a new page.I know it sounds so simple, but how do I navigate back to the  page I was on previously? ....(I have the same problem with **Gmail**)

(I would like to be able to continue working in the way I did with **Windows 7**; if that is possible.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my dilemma: Whenever I navigated back to **desktop**,  I did so by "grabbing" the current page from the top and "dragging" it down; thereby destroying it. I should rather, have navigated via the pop-up window in the top left corner of the screen, thereby conserving the present page..(elementary, my dear Watson)